# After a git merge --squash, delete the feature or keep it and merge master into it?

Tags: git

I delete feature branches after squashed merges to master when collaborating but I merge master back into the feature when I'm on my own.

Is that `harmful' as in potentially destructive like a rebase on a public branch? 
Or just pointless/ineffective as in more typework/whatever?

Reason I'm asking is that I just keep a single branch for hacking around, called hacking and deleting and recreating it feels odd to me if it's not a branch for a specific feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History you never push is entirely your own, nothing but your own use matters, so whatever makes the history of your own branches look sensible, that's the way to go.